# Por qué sucede este error? forEach Javascript

Tags: javascript

***No me imprime los numeros***

```js
// forEach LOOP IN ARRAY

var any1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var saveEach = forEachsimplex; // for execute

function forEachsimplex() {
var divforEach = document.getElementById("forEach");

function f() {
any1.forEach(function(i){
  
 
  creatediv(i, divforEach);
  
});

}

return f;


}

// for all body

function creatediv(texto, div) {
  
  var p = document.createElement('P');
  var text = document.createTextNode(texto);
  p.appendChild(text);
  document.getElementById(div).appendChild(p);
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="learn.js"></script>
  <style>
    #forEach {width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: white; position: absolute;}
  </style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="forEach">
    
    <h4 style="text-align:center;">Simplex forEach LOOP</h4>
    <script>saveEach();</script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Porque saveEach no está definida y al intentar ejecutarla como na función pues te peta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el código hay dos fallos.
El primero es que en `forEachsimplex` retornas "`f`" que es la función en si, y debería ser "`f()`" que es la respuesta.
El segundo es que el segundo parámetro de "`creatediv`" le asignas un elemento, y la función espera una ID, ya que luego hace un `getElementByID`, y en este caso no hace falta.
Una posible solución al código:

```js
// forEach LOOP IN ARRAY
var any1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var saveEach = forEachsimplex; // for execute

function forEachsimplex() {
 var divforEach = document.getElementById("forEach");
 function f() {
  any1.forEach(function(i){
   creatediv(i, divforEach);
  });
 }
 return f(); // <- bug, falta ()
}

function creatediv(texto, div) {
  var p = document.createElement('P');
  var text = document.createTextNode(texto);
  p.appendChild(text);
  div.appendChild(p); // <-- bug, div ya es el elemento
}
saveEach();
```

```css
#forEach {width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: white; position: absolute;}
```

```html
<div id="forEach">
    <h4 style="text-align:center;">Simplex forEach LOOP</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Me ha servido , pero me gustaría saber porqué f() y no f , yo pensaba que se le pasaba solo una referencia y me gustaría si me das documentación por favor

Comment: Haciendo return f; estas retornando la función f, no la respuesta a su ejecución, que ni si quiera llega a hacerlo.
Haciendo return f(); , ejecuta la función y retorna su respuesta (que en este caso concreto no responde nada ya que 'f' no tiene return);.

Answer (score 0):

tienes varios errores en el script, un par son de concepto asi que vamos por partes:

**Error 1: saveEach(); no hace nada**

Por que habría de hacerlo? saveEach (alias de forEachsimplex) es una función que devuelve otra función, por lo que el resultado de saveEach es el que debería ejecutarse:

```
<script>
  var f = saveEach();
  f();
</script>
```

**Error 2: divforEach no esta definido.**

Una vez que f trata de ejecutarse, divforEach no está definido, es porque ya no estamos en el scope de forEachsimplex, por lo que var divforEach ahora es undefined, una solucion es mover la linea dentro de la funcion F

```
function f() {
  var divforEach = document.getElementById("forEach");
  any1.forEach(function(i){
    creatediv(i, divforEach);
  });
}
```

**Error 3: document.getElementById is null**

Al solucionar los errores de arriba, la función se ejecuta correctamente, PERO tenemos un error de concepto en create div:

document.getElementById(div).appendChild(p);

getElementById esa esperando que le pasemos un string de un id, PERO le estamos pasando un Node. tenemos dos soluciones:

```
creatediv(i, "forEach"); //en funcion f
```

o

```
div.appendChild(p); //en creatediv
```

Todo junto:

```
var any1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

function forEachsimplex() {
  any1.forEach(function(i){
    creatediv(i, 'forEach');
  });
}

// for all body

function creatediv(texto, div) {
  var p = document.createElement('P');
  var text = document.createTextNode(texto);
  p.appendChild(text);
  document.getElementById(div).appendChild(p);
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="learn.js"></script>
  <style>
    #forEach {width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: white; position: absolute;}
  </style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="forEach">
    <h4 style="text-align:center;">Simplex forEach LOOP</h4>
  </div>
<script>
  forEachsimplex();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```